# Sharing actions between models in mobx-state-tree

Tags: mobx, mobx-state-tree

I would like to ask you if there's any way of sharing actions between models in `mobx-state-tree`?

Let's consider this example (`login` action of `AuthModel`):

```js
import { types } from "mobx-state-tree";

const UIModel = types
  .model({
    globalLoading: types.boolean,
  })
  .actions((self) => ({
    setGlobalLoading(value) {
      self.globalLoading = value;
    },
  }));

const AuthModel = types
  .model({
    userData: types.maybeNull(types.User),
  })
  .actions((self) => ({
    login() {
      // call UIModel.setGlobalLoading(true) somehow
    },
  }));

const RootModel = types.model({
  ui: UIModel,
  auth: AuthModel,
});

RootModel.create({
  auth: {
    userData: null
  },
  ui: {
    globalLoading: false
  }
})
```

Is there any way to somehow "inject" reference to UIModel inside AuthModel? I can't find anything like this in docs or examples I've seen online.